# What is the limit of number of keys i can import in java keystore?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, keystore, keytool

I have a scenario where i need to store many private/public keys in java keystore instance and use them for various purpose. Number of keys that i store in here could grow to thousands. Is it a better approach to store/load huge number of keys into keystore? And if not, what could be other better options?

My application runs on AWS and i will have multiple instances running that would need the keys from this keystore. Each instance having separate keystore instance could work, but is there also any option to share the keystore instance across my application instances?

I have explored AWS certificate manager and somehow it does not fulfill my requirement. I want a keystore to work as a database for public/private keys but i have large number of keys.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits to a java keystore.

btw this has been already asked: [java keystore file limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201672/java-keystore-file-limitations)